# Using a USB Bluetooth dongle on a Pi 3

Tags: usb, bluetooth

I am trying to get a Bluetooth dongle working on the Raspberry Pi 3, which has Bluetooth on-board. But trying to get the dongle to work as well the on-board Bluetooth does not seem to work.

I would like to if possible have `hci0` and `hci1`, but not getting much luck.

If I run `lsusb`, you can see the device, but it wont recognize it as a Bluetooth dongle, anything particular I should be doing?

I have tried running `modprobe btusb`, but it says module not found.

Just maybe some direction to where I should look?

Also the USB Bluetooth Dongle I am trying to get to work stipulates I should disable existing Bluetooth, which I did via the blacklist, but still it won't list with `hcitool dev` either.

I have tried a number of different USB Bluetooth dongles, but all are giving the same result.

Answer (score 2):

In order to disable the on-board Bluetooth chip, you can add this line to your `config.txt` file :

```
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
```

In case you also need to disable the software part, you can stop it using this command:

```
 sudo systemctl disable hciuart
```

These commands are supposed to disable only the on-board Bluetooth chip, but I haven't actually tested them, as I don't have an external Bluetooth dongle.